# Sort for specific lines in text

Tags: sorting, vim, emacs, vi, nano

I have the given text:

```
# Blub
Hello this is a blub text.

# Bla
This is the bla text.

# Abba
Another text.
```

Is it possible to sort for the lines with the `#`? So that the resulting text is:

```
# Abba
Another text.

# Bla
This the bla text.

# Blub
Hello this is a blub text.
```

Preferably using vim or emacs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Emacs,

1. <kbd>M-x</kbd>`sort-regexp-fields`
2. Enter: `#[^#]*`
3. Enter: `\&`

The first regexp delimits the record, and the second specifies the key for sorting.

If you're at liberty to choose the marker character and use `*` instead of `#`, you may use org-mode's command `org-sort-entries` instead, which saves you from entering the regexps.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
:sort! /^#.+\n.+\n$/
```

I'm not sure about line block order.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tag it as such, but I think `awk` is the best tool for the job. Using `gawk` the following works:

```
gawk RS='\n\n' '{ 
  gsub("\n$", "")
  gsub("\n", "@")
  print 
}' file_to_be_sorted | sort | sed -e 's/$/\n/' -e 's/@/\n/'
```

#### Explanation

By setting the record separator (RS) to '\n\n' `gawk` creates records from each block. Each record is converted to be on one line with `@` as separator (`gsub("\n", "@")`), at this point normal `sort` works. `sed` is then used to recreate the blocks. `gsub("\n$", "")` fixes a whitespace issue with the last record.

Note: if any of the blocks contains `@` you need to choose a different separator.